# Unity Increasing a value and then decrease it (DayNightCycle)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a cycle and want the cycle bar, having a value range from 0 to 1 and back to 0.

[image]

So, currently I use this code

```
public class DayNightCycle : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float currentTime = 0; // current time of the day
    private float secondsPerDay = 120; // maximum time per day
    private Image cycleBar; // ui bar

    private void Start()
    {
        cycleBar = GetComponent<Image>(); // reference
        UpdateCycleBar(); // update the ui
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        currentTime += Time.deltaTime; // increase the time
        if (currentTime >= secondsPerDay) // day is over?
            currentTime = 0; // reset time

        UpdateCycleBar(); // update ui
    }

    private void UpdateCycleBar()
    {
        cycleBar.rectTransform.localScale = new Vector3(currentTime / secondsPerDay, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

but now I want a behaviour as mentioned by the picture above. How can I increase `currentTime` from 0 to 1 and then back to 0?

The problem: My cycle bar should still increase from the left to the right.

The night should last 40% of the maximum time, the other ones 20%.

Comment: Assign the value 1 to the end of your "image". What i mean is do not make 1 as the middle of your day, make it end of your night as on the image, which will be middle of the night in terms. And then make your time to 0 when it reaches to 1 ?

Comment: Just add a flag, if that flag is true, then increase your count, if you reach the 1, then change your flag to false and then start decreasing your count to 0, at that point, change your flag to true and so...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to increase a variable from `0` to `1` then from `1` to `0`, [`Mathf.PingPong`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PingPong.html) is the answer. There are many other ways to do this but [`Mathf.PingPong`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PingPong.html) is made for tasks like this one.

```
public float speed = 1.19f;

void Update()
{
    //PingPong between 0 and 1
    float time = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * speed, 1);
    Debug.Log(time);
}
```

Comment: Didn't noticed that before, but you're right, that's the way.

Comment: yes this works fine, but do you got some help for the UI problem? Currently I use this code https://hastebin.com/soresunesu.cs but as you can image, `currentTime` and `currentBarTime` will not run synchronous.

Comment: Not sure this is the best way, because it's not just day and night but also dawn and dusk so using PingPong will make dusk appear before dawn.

Comment: @FLX Look at the title and the body of the question. *"How can I increase currentTime from 0 to 1 and then back to 0?"* This answers the question of going back on forth between 0 and 1. Nothing more. Maybe OP should've asked a different question but this answers the current question 100%.

Comment: @Question3r You need to ask a new question about your UI problem.

Comment: @Programmer Hmm, you're right. However, there is 2 zeros in his example, so "back to 0" can be read both ways I guess :)

Comment: Yes, I will start a new question about the UI :)

Answer (score 1):

Do this by Mathf.Sin() function. But you must get absolute value of it. Mathf.abs(mathf.sin());
It will change between 0 to 1 then back to zero. But its not smooth in zero.

Or offset sin function by +1 at the end multiply it by 0.5f to let it back to one again.

```
float timer = 0;
float cycle = 0;
public float speed = 1;

void Update()
{
    timer += Time.deltaTime;
    Cycle();
}

void Cycle()
{
    cycle = (Mathf.Sin(timer) + 1) * 0.5f;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but `(Mathf.Sin(timer)+1) * 0.5f;` is not a valid syntax

Comment: i change it for you, i thought that you can do this by some points. try the edited one.

Comment: but cycle will be always 0 because timer is always on 0 ?

Comment: i edit this code again. btw, you can do something else for your left night and right night. because these kind of codes that we have in these answers, starts from 0 to 1 and then back to 0, it means that you back from night to dusk again and not start from day. i can get you another code for this problem if you want

Comment: and when do u reset the variable `timer` ? Because maybe it could grow bigger than `float.MaxValue`. And I don't need the variable `speed`right? It is not used somewhere. This example works thank you. If you want, you can show me your other example

Comment: it will never become bigger that 1 and lower than 0, its sine! so you can use my another answer...

Answer (score 1):

instead of 0 to 1, use -1 to 1.

The timer starts from -1, increase in update function by deltaTime, and then when it will become moreThan equal 1 it will be reset to -1. its a loop...

```
float timer = -1;

void Update()
{
  timer += Time.deltaTime;

  if(timer >= 1)
  {
    timer = -1;
  }
    Cycle();
}

void Cycle()
{
    //Do Your Cycle
//-1 is left night, 0 is middle day, 1 is right night
}
```

Comment: While this code might work, it's far better to explain how or why this is a solution.

Comment: Yes this works, but it needs to stay between 0 and 1 :/

Comment: you can increase your timer from zero to 120, then divide it by 120, and when it will become more than 1, set it to 0...